# SharePoint 2013 - JavaScript: Why isn't my CAML query filtering my list data?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I'm trying to display data from a list on my SharePoint 2013 site using JavaScript. I'm able to display the data from the list, but I'm also trying to filter that data using a CAML query. My code is working with no errors displayed, but it's displaying all of the items from the list instead of the filtered list of results that I'm expecting. Please see my code below and let me know if I'm doing anything wrong:

```
function GetListItemsFromSPList(listId) {   
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);
    var query =  new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml('<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' /><Value Type=\'Single line of text\'>CR1</Value></Eq></Where></Query>');
    var queryResults = list.getItems(query);
    context.load(queryResults);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { onQuerySuccess(queryResults); }),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySuccess(allItems) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var ListEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();
    while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) 
    {
        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();

        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + currentItem.get_id() + ", Title: " + currentItem.get_item('Title') + ", ContractNo: " + currentItem.get_item('ContractNo');

    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the column in your CAML query should be "Text" instead of "Single line of text". Try changing that line to:

```
query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>CR1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Damjan. I changed the query as you suggested, and it's still returning all of the items in the list.

Comment: Note that I also added <View> element that surrounds the <Query> element. Did you try to add that too?

Comment: No I missed that. Adding the View element worked. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.